# SQL Flattening data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm by no means a SQL expert and just about know my way around it.

I need to flatten some data in order to produce it for SQL Reporting purposes.

Herewith my query which I don't think is optimal since it's slow and I'm sure there are 10 better way to do this:

The core column here is InspectionID which is the primary key on Inspections table

Any advice?

```
SELECT      
    INSP.HouseSiteNo,
    (SELECT TOP 1 WORKFLOWSTATES.Name FROM INSPECTIONWORKFLOWITEM WFITEM 
        INNER JOIN WORKFLOWSTATES ON WFITEM.WorkflowStateID = WORKFLOWSTATES.WorkflowStateID
        WHERE WFITEM.InspectionID = INSP.InspectionID AND WORKFLOWSTATES.StateNumber = 1) as StateName
    FROM INSPECTIONS INSP       
ORDER BY HouseSiteNo
```

The table structures as follow:

INSPECTIONS:

```
HouseSiteNo     HouseType    ProjectID                              InspectionID
1                A           543C6381-8704-4129-B484-05B02927F690   E061F76F-8998-450B-B08C-DA2817B310A4
2                A           543C6381-8704-4129-B484-05B02927F690   E0D1F3DB-51D4-465A-A0B4-ACFFF181DC56
```

INSPECTIONWORKFLOWITEM

```
InspectionID                            WorkflowStateID                         DateStarted               StateCompleted    ID
FAA4E366-1D57-4699-982C-001FF351D717    AB2B7DA0-A90A-46FB-8F4B-8E662191E380    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   D77332CB-D026-409A-814D-5632C109850A
FAA4E366-1D57-4699-982C-001FF351D717    E2AC895A-0986-4A03-B104-A727D41405E3    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   F118FD02-20C4-4B45-8539-6F8BDC6B3868
FAA4E366-1D57-4699-982C-001FF351D717    F0469593-1B6B-4F98-92AE-DF50E76B9ED8    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   8FBEE61B-D7B3-4D13-9FC8-730EB0FE7C95
FAA4E366-1D57-4699-982C-001FF351D717    5929D0CA-E8B0-42EE-9CF4-E3FBC9973AA6    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   02646FE5-B338-4D6F-B5F5-7984B0EF7BF5
FAA4E366-1D57-4699-982C-001FF351D717    ECDDB790-88A4-4654-889D-BCA577C35CA8    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   0B9C26FA-8D9D-4552-A3FE-84D4D21F5791
FAA4E366-1D57-4699-982C-001FF351D717    099D66A4-16F2-4E72-A42A-06B4D6DC0102    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   3B90F113-5194-4ED2-B920-8DA004C9EA5C
FAA4E366-1D57-4699-982C-001FF351D717    66132F53-0A0E-431A-AD84-ADE77656CDF0    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   05223484-8BB3-43A8-A9A8-C8FBC6270186
9AC52A0A-BC2D-4BBD-9585-0028C07ACC27    F0469593-1B6B-4F98-92AE-DF50E76B9ED8    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   A1471AF4-B733-488C-86B4-FB29970E536E
9AC52A0A-BC2D-4BBD-9585-0028C07ACC27    ECDDB790-88A4-4654-889D-BCA577C35CA8    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   30F3A1F9-6E51-4504-A9FD-B32FD2B35B39
9AC52A0A-BC2D-4BBD-9585-0028C07ACC27    5929D0CA-E8B0-42EE-9CF4-E3FBC9973AA6    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   760D4907-ED6C-4D84-AED9-775FBBAE5123
9AC52A0A-BC2D-4BBD-9585-0028C07ACC27    AB2B7DA0-A90A-46FB-8F4B-8E662191E380    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   49D632C7-31D0-4818-AC36-564F157D1959
9AC52A0A-BC2D-4BBD-9585-0028C07ACC27    66132F53-0A0E-431A-AD84-ADE77656CDF0    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   C6771081-198D-475B-BA09-14BB696567DA
9AC52A0A-BC2D-4BBD-9585-0028C07ACC27    099D66A4-16F2-4E72-A42A-06B4D6DC0102    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   F265B140-25C5-46CA-B060-2A27CD9F9D00
9AC52A0A-BC2D-4BBD-9585-0028C07ACC27    E2AC895A-0986-4A03-B104-A727D41405E3    2012-09-09 00:00:00.000 0   E56AEC15-4BA1-4089-B1A7-3BF054568929
```

WORKFLOWSTATES

```
WorkflowStateID                         Name          StateNumber
099D66A4-16F2-4E72-A42A-06B4D6DC0102    State 3     3
AB2B7DA0-A90A-46FB-8F4B-8E662191E380    State 6     6
E2AC895A-0986-4A03-B104-A727D41405E3    State 1     1
66132F53-0A0E-431A-AD84-ADE77656CDF0    State 2     2
ECDDB790-88A4-4654-889D-BCA577C35CA8    State 5     5
F0469593-1B6B-4F98-92AE-DF50E76B9ED8    State 7     7
5929D0CA-E8B0-42EE-9CF4-E3FBC9973AA6    State 4     4
```

Comment: You forgot to show the WORKFLOWSTATES table (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd43e/1) and to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry about that, added it now, tx

Comment: Also, the question I'm asking is.. Am I doing it the right way? Is there no other way to flatten the data into a single row? We all know how trick SQL reports can be.. Tx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or newer you can use [cross/outer apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  INSP.HouseSiteNo, StateName.Name
FROM INSPECTIONS INSP 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WORKFLOWSTATES.Name FROM INSPECTIONWORKFLOWITEM WFITEM 
    INNER JOIN WORKFLOWSTATES ON WFITEM.WorkflowStateID = WORKFLOWSTATES.WorkflowStateID
    WHERE WFITEM.InspectionID = INSP.InspectionID AND WORKFLOWSTATES.StateNumber = 1
) StateName
ORDER BY HouseSiteNo
```

<del>when I run this two queries in one batch actual execution plan shows that your query cost relative to batch is 68% and mine 32% - so it's huge performance gain.</del> Performance gain was caused by lack of `ORDER BY` statment. Currently both of them are 50% relative to batch.

Comment: Hi. This works very well, except that my query is going to be quite big. The problem is that the CROSS APPLY will have to be copied a few times because I have 7 Workflowstates. Also, there are other column I'd also like to extract

Comment: I could propably put the cross join in a function and keep calling it?

Comment: @Fox Can you add to question exact output you want to have?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

If your query takes a long time and works, try running it through the analyzer and seeing if there are indexes you can add to boost performance.

```
SELECT i.HouseSiteNo, w.Name
FROM Inspections i
JOIN InspectionWorkflowItem wfi on i.InspectionID = wfi.InspectionID
JOIN WorkflowStatus w on w.WorkflowStateID = wfi.WorkflowStateID
WHERE w.StateNumber = 1
ORDER BY i.HouseSiteNo
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I have multiple record on InspectionWorkflowItem table. The only reason why your works is because of the WHERE clause. As soon as I remove the WHERE, I get multiple rows back...

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential problem.  Top 1 in absence of unique sort is non deterministic.
Even a table with a clustered PK is not guaranteed to return the same top 1 without a sort.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WORKFLOWSTATES.Name 
FROM INSPECTIONWORKFLOWITEM WFITEM 
INNER JOIN WORKFLOWSTATES 
   ON WFITEM.WorkflowStateID = WORKFLOWSTATES.WorkflowStateID
WHERE WFITEM.InspectionID = INSP.InspectionID 
  AND WORKFLOWSTATES.StateNumber = 1


SELECT INSP.HouseSiteNo, min(WORKFLOWSTATES.Name)  -- at least min is deterministic 
FROM FROM INSPECTIONS INSP 
JOIN INSPECTIONWORKFLOWITEM WFITEM
  ON WFITEM.InspectionID = INSP.InspectionID
JOIN WORKFLOWSTATES 
  ON WORKFLOWSTATES.WorkflowStateID = WFITEM.WorkflowStateID
 AND WORKFLOWSTATES.StateNumber = 1
GROUP BY INSP.HouseSiteNo
ORDER BY INSP.HouseSiteNo
```